# Display Data From A SQL Database In CRM Form

Tags: sql-server, database, dynamics-crm-2013

This is something completely unknown to me, but I have software called FM that stores data to a SQL Server Database, I want to be able to simply display certain fields in the records in my CRM form

Any suggestions/examples on how this can be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a webservice to fetch/expose the sql data, and after inside your CRM form you call this webservice to pull the data and display it inside the CRM form.

Comment: Hi @Guido how would I go about doing this?